# Why window.location doesn't redirect the page

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

I want to back my form upload page after success to upload.
alert is run well, but window location is not run.

Here my code. Thanks for help

```
 if ($uploadKey)
   {
?>
  <script>
          alert("Upload succesfull");
      window.location ('= form_upload.php');
  </script>

        <?php
    }
else{
     ?>
       <script>
           alert("Upload failed");
           window.location('=form_upload.php');
    </script>
<?php
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you cared to see the syntax? It should be

```
window.location = "PATH_TO_REDIRECT";
```

Also, you are using PHP, you should be using `header()` instead of `window.location`

```
if ($uploadKey) {
   header('Location: URL_HERE');
   exit;
}
```

Comment: @SinagamanEidelbert You welcome and I just checked your profile, if the answers helps you, you should mark them as correct, so that it will help the future visitors to refer to

Answer (score 1):

You have written wrong window.location syntax.
Please write as below:

```
window.location = "form_upload.php";
```

Instead of :

```
 window.location ('= form_upload.php');
```